# Octave not installing in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation

When I tried installing octave, it threw me an error saying the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 10.2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The full execution of the command is as follows:

```
prinshu@pk:~$ sudo apt-get install octave
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 10.2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output of `apt-get install -s -f octave libosmesa6` is as follows:

```
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rename
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aglfn debconf debconf-i18n gcc-7-base gnuplot-data gnuplot-x11 libaec0
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libamd2 libapparmor-perl libapt-pkg-perl
  libarpack2 libblas3 libcairo-perl libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcholmod3
  libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcolamd2 libcxsparse3 libemf1
  libfcgi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libfltk-gl1.3 libfltk1.3 libgfortran4
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl2ps1 libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa
  libglib-perl libglpk40 libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3
  libgtk2-perl libhdf5-100 libhtml-parser-perl libio-pty-perl liblapack3
  liblist-moreutils-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmetis5
  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl liboctave4
  libopenblas-base libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpango-perl
  libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl
  libperl5.26 libperlio-gzip-perl libplot2c2 libportaudio2 libpstoedit0c2a
  libqhull7 libqrupdate1 libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-opengl
  libscalar-list-utils-perl libsocket6-perl libsort-key-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libsuitesparseconfig4 libsz2
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-unidecode-perl libumfpack5
  libunicode-utf8-perl libuuid-perl libvariable-magic-perl libwxbase3.0-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl
  libxml-parser-perl libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl
  libxml-sax-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl libzip4 mesa-common-dev octave-common
  octave-info perl perl-base perl-modules-5.26 pstoedit tex-common texinfo
Suggested packages:
  debconf-doc debconf-utils libterm-readline-gnu-perl libnet-ldap-perl
  libqtgui4-perl libqtcore4-perl gnuplot-doc libfont-freetype-perl
  libiodbc2-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev graphicsmagick-dbg libgtk2-perl-doc
  libdata-dump-perl libscalar-number-perl octave-doc octave-htmldoc perl-doc
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl xfig | ivtools-bin
  | tgif | transfig debhelper texlive-base texlive-latex-base
  texlive-generic-recommended texinfo-doc-nonfree texlive-fonts-recommended
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aglfn gcc-7-base gnuplot-data gnuplot-x11 libaec0 libamd2 libarpack2
  libblas3 libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcholmod3 libcolamd2 libcxsparse3 libemf1
  libfltk-gl1.3 libfltk1.3 libgfortran4 libgl2ps1 libglpk40
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libhdf5-100 liblapack3
  libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmetis5 liboctave4 libopenblas-base libosmesa6
  libperl5.26 libplot2c2 libportaudio2 libpstoedit0c2a libqhull7 libqrupdate1
  libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-opengl libsuitesparseconfig4
  libsz2 libtext-unidecode-perl libumfpack5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
  libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl
  libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl libzip4 octave octave-common
  octave-info perl-modules-5.26 pstoedit tex-common texinfo
The following packages will be upgraded:
  debconf debconf-i18n libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl
  libapt-pkg-perl libcairo-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl
  libfcgi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa libglib-perl libgtk2-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libio-pty-perl liblist-moreutils-perl liblocale-gettext-perl
  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpango-perl libparams-classify-perl
  libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
  libscalar-list-utils-perl libsocket6-perl libsort-key-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libunicode-utf8-perl libuuid-perl libvariable-magic-perl
  libxml-parser-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl mesa-common-dev perl perl-base
44 upgraded, 56 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1327 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Inst debconf-i18n [1.5.59ubuntu1] (1.5.63 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all]) []
Inst debconf [1.5.59ubuntu1] (1.5.63 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf debconf (1.5.63 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst perl [5.24.1-2ubuntu1] (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) [libclass-xsaccessor-perl:amd64 ]
Inst perl-modules-5.26 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all]) [libclass-xsaccessor-perl:amd64 ]
Inst libperl5.26 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) [libclass-xsaccessor-perl:amd64 ]
Inst libclass-xsaccessor-perl [1.19-2build6] (1.19-2build7 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst liblist-moreutils-perl [0.416-1build2] (0.416-1build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libgtk2-perl [2:1.2499-1] (2:1.24992-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libsort-key-perl [1.33-1build4] (1.33-1build5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libapparmor-perl [2.11.0-2ubuntu4] (2.11.0-2ubuntu17 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libfcgi-perl [0.78-2] (0.78-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libparams-classify-perl [0.013-6build2] (0.013-8build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libyaml-libyaml-perl [0.63-2] (0.63-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libpango-perl [1.227-1build1] (1.227-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libsub-name-perl [0.21-1] (0.21-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libparams-util-perl [1.07-3build2] (1.07-3build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libunicode-utf8-perl [0.60-1build3] (0.60-1build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libtext-charwidth-perl [0.04-7build6] (0.04-7.1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libclone-perl [0.38-2build1] (0.38-2build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libxml-parser-perl [2.44-2build2] (2.44-2build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libhtml-parser-perl [3.72-3] (3.72-3build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libscalar-list-utils-perl [1:1.47-1] (1:1.48-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libtext-iconv-perl [1.7-5build5] (1.7-5build6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libuuid-perl [0.27-1] (0.27-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libsocket6-perl [0.27-1build1] (0.27-1build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl [0.04-4build2] (0.04-4build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libpackage-stash-xs-perl [0.28-3build1] (0.28-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libfile-fcntllock-perl [0.22-3build1] (0.22-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libparams-validate-perl [1.26-1] (1.29-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libsub-identify-perl [0.12-2build2] (0.12-2build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libnet-dbus-perl [1.1.0-4build1] (1.1.0-4build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libnet-ssleay-perl [1.80-1] (1.80-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libvariable-magic-perl [0.61-1] (0.61-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libperlio-gzip-perl [0.19-1build2] (0.19-1build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libio-pty-perl [1:1.08-1.1build3] (1:1.08-1.1build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libcairo-perl [1.106-1build2] (1.106-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libapt-pkg-perl [0.1.30] (0.1.33 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libnet-libidn-perl [0.12.ds-2build3] (0.12.ds-2build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libglib-perl [3:1.324-1] (3:1.326-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst perl-base [5.24.1-2ubuntu1] (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) [liblocale-gettext-perl:amd64 on perlapi-5.24.1:amd64] [liblocale-gettext-perl:amd64 ]
Conf perl-base (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) [liblocale-gettext-perl:amd64 ]
Inst liblocale-gettext-perl [1.07-3build1] (1.07-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst tex-common (6.09 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst gcc-7-base (7.2.0-8ubuntu3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst aglfn (1.7-3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst gnuplot-data (5.0.7+dfsg1-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libwxbase3.0-0v5 (3.0.3.1+dfsg2-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libgl1-mesa-dev [17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1] (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst mesa-common-dev [17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1] (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libgles2-mesa [17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1] (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libgl1-mesa-glx [17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1] (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) []
Inst libglapi-mesa [17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1] (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (3.0.3.1+dfsg2-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst gnuplot-x11 (5.0.7+dfsg1-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libaec0 (0.3.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libsuitesparseconfig4 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libblas3 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libgfortran4 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libopenblas-base (0.2.20+ds-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst liblapack3 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libarpack2 (3.5.0+real-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libcamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libccolamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libcolamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libmetis5 (5.1.0.dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libcholmod3 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libcxsparse3 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libemf1 (1.0.9+git.10.3231442-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libfltk1.3 (1.3.4-6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libfltk-gl1.3 (1.3.4-6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libgl2ps1 (1.3.9-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libglpk40 (4.63-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 (1.3.26-15 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 (1.3.26-15 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libsz2 (0.3.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-100 (1.10.0-patch1+docs-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libmagick++-6.q16-7 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libqrupdate1 (1.1.2-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libumfpack5 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst liboctave4 (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libplot2c2 (2.6-7 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libportaudio2 (19.6.0-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libzip4 (1.1.2-1.1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libpstoedit0c2a (3.70-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libqhull7 (2015.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libqscintilla2-l10n (2.9.3+dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libqscintilla2-12v5 (2.9.3+dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libqt4-opengl (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libtext-unidecode-perl (1.30-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libxml-namespacesupport-perl (1.11-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libxml-sax-base-perl (1.07-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libxml-sax-perl (0.99+dfsg-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst libxml-libxml-perl (2.0128+dfsg-3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libxml-sax-expat-perl (0.40-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst pstoedit (3.70-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst texinfo (6.4.90.dfsg.1-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst libosmesa6 (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst octave-common (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Inst octave (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Inst octave-info (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf debconf-i18n (1.5.63 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf perl (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf perl-modules-5.26 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libperl5.26 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libclass-xsaccessor-perl (1.19-2build7 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf liblist-moreutils-perl (0.416-1build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgtk2-perl (2:1.24992-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsort-key-perl (1.33-1build5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libapparmor-perl (2.11.0-2ubuntu17 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libfcgi-perl (0.78-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libparams-classify-perl (0.013-8build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libyaml-libyaml-perl (0.63-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libpango-perl (1.227-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsub-name-perl (0.21-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libparams-util-perl (1.07-3build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libunicode-utf8-perl (0.60-1build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libtext-charwidth-perl (0.04-7.1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libclone-perl (0.38-2build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libxml-parser-perl (2.44-2build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-3build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libscalar-list-utils-perl (1:1.48-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libtext-iconv-perl (1.7-5build6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libuuid-perl (0.27-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsocket6-perl (0.27-1build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-4build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libpackage-stash-xs-perl (0.28-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libparams-validate-perl (1.29-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsub-identify-perl (0.12-2build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libnet-dbus-perl (1.1.0-4build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libnet-ssleay-perl (1.80-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libvariable-magic-perl (0.61-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libperlio-gzip-perl (0.19-1build3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libio-pty-perl (1:1.08-1.1build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libcairo-perl (1.106-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libapt-pkg-perl (0.1.33 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libnet-libidn-perl (0.12.ds-2build4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libglib-perl (3:1.326-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf liblocale-gettext-perl (1.07-3build2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf tex-common (6.09 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf gcc-7-base (7.2.0-8ubuntu3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf aglfn (1.7-3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf gnuplot-data (5.0.7+dfsg1-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libwxbase3.0-0v5 (3.0.3.1+dfsg2-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgl1-mesa-dev (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf mesa-common-dev (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgles2-mesa (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgl1-mesa-glx (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libglapi-mesa (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (3.0.3.1+dfsg2-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf gnuplot-x11 (5.0.7+dfsg1-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libaec0 (0.3.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsuitesparseconfig4 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libblas3 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgfortran4 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libopenblas-base (0.2.20+ds-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf liblapack3 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libarpack2 (3.5.0+real-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libcamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libccolamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libcolamd2 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libmetis5 (5.1.0.dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libcholmod3 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libcxsparse3 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libemf1 (1.0.9+git.10.3231442-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libfltk1.3 (1.3.4-6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libfltk-gl1.3 (1.3.4-6 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgl2ps1 (1.3.9-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libglpk40 (4.63-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 (1.3.26-15 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 (1.3.26-15 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libsz2 (0.3.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-100 (1.10.0-patch1+docs-4 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libmagick++-6.q16-7 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libqrupdate1 (1.1.2-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libumfpack5 (1:4.5.5-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf liboctave4 (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libplot2c2 (2.6-7 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libportaudio2 (19.6.0-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libzip4 (1.1.2-1.1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libpstoedit0c2a (3.70-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libqhull7 (2015.2-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libqscintilla2-l10n (2.9.3+dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libqscintilla2-12v5 (2.9.3+dfsg-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libqt4-opengl (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libtext-unidecode-perl (1.30-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libxml-namespacesupport-perl (1.11-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libxml-sax-base-perl (1.07-1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libxml-sax-perl (0.99+dfsg-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf libxml-libxml-perl (2.0128+dfsg-3 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libxml-sax-expat-perl (0.40-2 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf pstoedit (3.70-5 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf texinfo (6.4.90.dfsg.1-1build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf libosmesa6 (17.2.2-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf octave-common (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf octave (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64])
Conf octave-info (4.2.1-2build1 Ubuntu:17.10/artful [all])
Conf oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1  [all])
Conf oracle-java7-set-default (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1  [all])
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-get install -s -f octave libosmesa6`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install -s -f octave libosmesa6`.

It seems like the package is installing fine in the simulation, so now you just have to run the command in root and see how it goes.